# Добавить прокси к моему приложению на Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proxy, прокси

Я хочу узнать как правильно добавить прокси к моему приложению. Так получилось, что сайт, который я парсю попал в реестр РКН, мне нужен способ продолжить работу моего приложения, чтобы пользователю не пришлось думать об этом.

Мне не нужны сторонние приложения, мне нужно пользоваться только встроенными библиотеками Android или API.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вы можете реализовать самостоятельно поддержку тунелирования трафика, это не сложно, почитайте например про протокол Socks 5 или 4(реже встречается)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой пример соединения через proxy:

```
String proxyHost = "PROXY_URL";
int proxyPort = PROXY_PORT;
InetSocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxyAddr);

URL request = new URL("BANNED_URL");

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) request.openConnection(proxy);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(36000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(44000);
```